# Почему не работает перенаправление на страницу?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Реализую авторизацию на сайте без использования форм, чтобы не отправлять пароль на сервер.

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/login.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block">
            <p id="autorization">Вход</p>
            <div class="form">
                <p><label>Логин<br><input type="text" id="username"></label></p>
                <p><label>Пароль<br><input type="password" id="password"></label></p>
                <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="remember">Запомнить меня</label></p>
                <p><button id="submit">Отправить</button></p>

                {% for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
                    {% if category == 'error' %}
                        <p class="error-msg">{{ message }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" выполняется метод onsubmit.

login.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let submit = document.querySelector('button#submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', onsubmit)
};

 function onsubmit() {
        let username = document.querySelector('input#username').value;

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let send = JSON.stringify({'username': username});
        xhr.open('POST', '/get-password-data', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xhr.send(send);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if ('salt' in data && 'hash' in data) {
                    let password = document.querySelector('input#password').value;
                    let remember = document.querySelector('input#remember').value === 'on';
                    let hash = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, data.salt,
                        {keySize: 512/32, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, iterations: 10000});
                    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    let send = JSON.stringify({
                        'username': username,
                        'hash': hash.toString(),
                        'remember': remember
                    });
                    xhr.open('POST', '/login/', true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                    xhr.send(send);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        console.log(xhr.readyState, xhr.responseText)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Все это дело обрабатывает Flask приложение.

auth/views.py

```
@auth.route('/get-password-data', methods=['POST'])
def get_password_data():
    data = request.get_json()  # {'username': username}
    username = data['username']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    if user:
        response = {
            'salt': user.password_salt,
            'hash': user.password_hash
        }
        return json.dumps(response), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
    return (json.dumps({'message': 'No user'}), 200,
            {'ContentType': 'application/json'})

@auth.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # data == {'username': str, 'hash': str, 'remember': bool}
        data = request.get_json()
        user = db.session.query(User).filter(
            User.username == data['username']).first()
        if user and user.password_hash == data['hash']:
            login_user(user, remember=data['remember'])
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        flash(u'Неверный логин/пароль', 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Когда пользователь вводит некорректный пароль, должно произойти перенаправление на /login/ + вывести сообщение об ошибке (cм. в шаблоне цикл по сообщениям). Если пользователь ввел корректный пароль, то должно произойти перенаправление на страницу main.index ('/').

Этого не происходит. Т.е. при вводе корректного пароля, страница не переходит '/', но пользователь считается авторизованным, т.к. если самому перезапустить страницу /login/ перенаправит на '/' (это из-за условия в начале функции login).
Ну и при вводе некорректного пароля тоже ничего не происходит. Хотя, если вывести ответ сервера на POST запрос /login/, видно, что возвращается страница, на которую должно произойти перенаправление.

Раньше, когда использовал форму для авторизации, все работало, при этом обработчик '/login/' выглядел следующим образом:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = StringField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField("Remember Me")
    submit = SubmitField()

@auth.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = db.session.query(User).filter(
            User.username == form.username.data).first()
        if user and user.check_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

        flash(u'Неверный логин/пароль', 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Вопрос: почему не работает перенаправление?

Comment: А вы не думали что форму перед отправкой можно прогнать через валидацию, и там применить к ней хэш? зачем это извращение без "форм" ?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, спасибо за идею, попробую.

Comment: А вы можете пояснить, в чем смысл такой защиты? Как она работает? От чего защищает?

Comment: Искал способ не передавать пароль на сервер. В данном вопросе меня интересует почему не работает перенаправление после запроса, а не "от чего защищает".

Comment: А меня в данном вопросе интересует, *от чего защищает*.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я же выше вам сказал: чтобы не передавать пароль через форму. Все уже исправил как посоветовал Владимир. Вопрос был про обновление страницы. Как мне сказали, после запроса из js (ajax) нужно самому перезапустить страницу через js, url страницы нужно передать в ответе клиенту.

Comment: Я же у вас спрашиваю, от чего защитит такая логика, а не для чего вы это делаете. Хорошо, вы не передаете пароль на сервер. Но как это поможет улучшить безопасность? У вас есть эндпоинт `/get-password-data`, который возвращает хеш пароля. Что мне, как злоумышлинику, мешает передать в эндпоинт `/login` этот хеш?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я уже понял ошибку и исправил ее.

Comment: @ioprst я рад за вас! Хорошо бы тогда написать ответ к вашему вопросу. Но игнорировать вопросы собеседника (мои вопросы) - как минимум не культурно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я извиняюсь, если чем то обидел, вас, но я не игнорировал. Я вам описал проблему с которой столкнулся: передача открытого пароля в форме, решение которой я и искал. Поэтому экспериментировал. Ответа на ваш вопрос "от чего защищает" у меня нет, т.к. выходит за рамки моего вопроса (возможно и знаний, т.к. только начал изучать эту тему).

Comment: Как это выходит за рамки вопроса? У вас возник вопрос, из-за того что вы решаете проблему странными методами. Возможно, надо пересмотреть способ решения да и саму проблему, чем делать костыли :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну пусть будет так :) Я ошибся, исправил: от сервера клиент получает только соль, вычисляет хэш и кидает его серверу. Это стандартный подход? (не сарказм).

Comment: Если честно, я не знаю, какой подход стандартный. Я не видел реализаций, в которых бы не передавался пароль.

Comment: Была статья на хабре (https://habr.com/ru/post/121021/), где использовался протокол SRP. Не проверял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить перенаправление средствами JS.

Сервер на запрос возвращает url для перехода. В JS вызывается `window.location.href = url;`.